# how to remove <p> tag when writing to textarea in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel.I have a laravelcollective textarea in my blade that I store its value in a database:

```
{!! Form::textarea('TaskDsc',null,['style'=>'height: 113px;width:150%;','class'=>'p-2']) !!}
```

When I write the text in several lines and save it in the database, the `<p>` tag is stored with them inside the table.

```
<p> line 1 </p><p> line 1 </p>
```

When I write the text in several lines and save it in the table, the `<p>` tag is added inside the table.
The problem is that when I read the data from the table and display it in the textarea in edit blade , it is displayed with the `<p>` tag and as it is stored in the database. While I want the `<p>` tag
Delete and display each paragraph separately and below

```
line1
line2
```

Comment: 'when I read the data from the table and display it in the textarea in edit blade' can you share this specific code in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all `<p>` by `\n` before input in textarea and replace all `\n` by `<p>` before save to database.

Comment: how to this in laravelcollective textarea?

Comment: by using strip_tags() n controller ,Two lines stick together and are not written below each other. How can I add /br between them?

Comment: In file `blade`, find your textarea input range and replace input string for its. `nl2br($strippedString)`. Or can you provide your code to more information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp))

```
{!! Form::textarea('TaskDsc', isset($TaskDsc) ? strip_tags($TaskDsc) : null, ['style'=>'height: 113px;width:150%;','class'=>'p-2']) !!}
```

**The `isset()` function is used to prevent errors in strip_tags when no value is passed.**

Comment: Two lines stick together and are not written under each other and in separate paragraphs